# Why isn't there "the" before "New Year" sometimes?

Tags: phrase-usage, definite-article, time

From [an article "At, on and in (time)" by Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/at-on-and-in-time):

> *At **the New Year**, millions of people travel home to be with their families.*

From [an entry for *new year* on Oxford Learner's Dictionaries](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/new-year?q=new+year):

> *We're going to Germany for Christmas and **New Year**.*

When do you use "the" before "New Year" or not? Does adding or removing "the" introduce any different nuance?

Comment: As an American English speaker, I would not say the second one. However, I would say it instead with "New Year's", which abbreviates "New Year's Day", which is a holiday name analogous to Christmas.

Comment: Also related: [When is the definite article needed before the name of a celebration?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/154277/)

Comment: @Mari-LouA https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/306481/127344 I think this answer is most related and answers my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Without "the", "New Year" is specifically about the Dec 31-January 1 turnover, with "the" it is about the upcoming year more generally. Your first example sentence the travel could really be taken any time prior to Jan 1, and last some unspecified time after. The second sentence is saying the travel to Germany is being done to be there specifically for Christmas and the Dec 31-Jan 1 turnover.

Comment: I'd say it refers to the *holiday* of New Year's Eve/Day, not just the turnover.